# Unknown Unicode characters

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding, special-characters

I would like to convert some characters, however dont know what is the origine name of those characters

Here you an example :

```
 €Ù¬Õ“
 ¤ ×ÑÊ…Ü­×“
 Ì“ÇØ®
 ¹”±”§Å£ 
 Ý«°¯²ÕÜ½°
```

Thank you

Comment: is this a one time thing or will you create a program to do it automatically? If not this is not a [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to ask here.

Comment: i would appreciate in php , but if i know what is the origine format is it , i can code something to convert it in php

Comment: Can you say more about the data? Is there a file that contains an encoding declaration?

Comment: original code is just a : eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode($string))); , i echo the output to show real code and in result some unknown characters , here is the full string , http://pastebin.com/uxDeGKTd

Comment: anyone got an idea ?